# Angular Running Controller twice on browser reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Problem:

I have an Angular app which works fine. It has 4 main page controllers which loaded inside the ng-view. All there controllers are connected to pages which routed via ngRoute.

When the app is loaded first time it works ok. But if I go to any of these pages and press browser's refresh(f5) the controllers are called twice. Is there any reason why they run once in the first instance and twice in a reload?

Comment: please share you code

Comment: Some code will help us to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Common problem, you must have loaded your controller on ui-router and also in the HTML file. Just remove it from HTML file, always use router to inject controllers, its just good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys it was an issue with a promise with a return.

After login in I had following code

```
....
$scope.someMethod().then(function(_data){
...
    if (something not related to _data) {
       $route.reload();
    } else {
       $location.path("xcxcxcxcxcx");
    }
...
})
```

in something method..

```
$scope.something = function(){
    var deff = $q.defer();
    ....
    APICALL.callAPI(xxxxx).then(function(data){
       deff.resolve(data);
    }, function(error) {
        deff.reject();
    });        
    return deff.promise;
};
```

The last return deff.promise returned the execution to the earlier method and ran $route..reload();

I am not 100% convinced but removing

> return deff.promise;

solved the issue.